# How do I implement page specific CSS in Ruby on Rails (5.2)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've removed `require_tree` and placed my CSS unique to a controller inside their respective asset files, and the CSS is not page specific. I'm guessing that I have to use `<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>` as indicated on the ruby on rails guide.

Does this mean that I remove the `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` located in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` and place the specific stylesheet tags into their respective views?

Or if there's another way to more effectively get CSS specific page, that too would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the popular solutions is adding a class in **application.html.erb** to a body like that:

```
<body class="<%= controller_name.underscore %>">
```

After you can use in different css files quite simple logic

```css
body.posts_controller {
  #posts {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `.underscore` in `<body class="<%= controller_name.underscore %>">`?

Comment: It's reverse of **camelize** method, take look on API https://apidock.com/rails/String/underscore

Comment: Is it possible that in a different version of ruby `<body class="<%= controller_name %>">` returns `PostsController` resulting in a need to use underscore? What I'm getting returned is simply `posts`. I'm double checking to make sure I understand this.

Comment: Yes, found correct API documentation for that method https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class